# Electron-forge - An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, squirrel

Tried to build an electron based app by running `npm run make` in terminal, everything went fine except when it had to go thru `Making distributables`. Out folder has been created but app is not bundled in one exe. 

 dependencies in Package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.3",
    "electron": "^6.1.12"
  },
```

config in forge.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

[Full error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g9bR.png)

 any solutions?

Comment: Hey there, we're working on fixing the `[object Object]` bug in the error logging. Forge v6.0.4 should provide a more descriptive error message going forward.

See https://github.com/electron/forge/pull/3086

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have author and description properties not empty in package.json like so:
"author": "John".

Here is a full example:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "John",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.3",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.3",
    "electron": "^21.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

It seems like a weird bug, but this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue and I fixed it by writing something in the description in the package.json file.

```
{
  ...
  description: "an electron test app",
  ...
}
```

https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/squirrel.windows#in-package.json

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[object Object]
```

Here [object object] indicates that some values are empty in the package.json file.

e.g. in my case it was author and description.

**Solution :**  Just provide some values other than empty, and `npm run make`  should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this config in `forge.config.js` and add `author` and `description` in your `package.json`

```
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        authors: 'My Name',
        description: 'My Description',
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As the selected answer mentions, this is due to a potential conflict in ES Modules and Common JS.

In my case, I had scaffolded with Vite and then ran `npx electron-forge import` and got this error.

A simple fix was to remove `"type":module` from `package.json`